# Change view class programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, textview, android-inflate

I'm using com.rockerhieu.emojicon library, which is working great but, when used on a recyclerview with a long text the scroll gets slow. For that reason I would like to use the EmojiconTextView just when an emoji must be shown. So, I would like to have a TextView element on my xml resource and convert it to EmojiconTextView programmatically just when needed. Is there a way to achieve that? I thought about using ViewStub, but I didn't find the way to inflate it with a TextView/EmojiconTextView element.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the declarative way of creating your UI using XML, try creating your UI programmatically.

Considering you have `LinerLayout` defined in your XML:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/linearMain"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

You can then add your `EmojiconTextView` and `TextView` programatically:

```
final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);

LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

if (mustShowEmoji) {
  EmojiconTextView etv = new EmojiconTextView(this);
  etv.setLayoutParams(lpView);
  etv.setText("TextView containing emoji");
  lm.addView(etv);        
} else {
  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
  tv.setLayoutParams(lpView);
  tv.setText("TextView");
  lm .addView(tv);        
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd thought about doing that, but then I would be adding an extra viewgroup on my tree of views, and I would like to avoid that. However, right now this seems to be the best solution. Thanks a lot